# answering a question that has a conflicting tag

Tags: discussion

A [question from 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270611) asked how to print some things in Scheme. The user mentioned that they were using Racket, which is a descendant of Scheme, [but not really compatible with Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345397/how-is-racket-different-from-scheme), but the question and title both specifically say how to do the printing in Scheme, not Racket. However, the user added a Racket tag.

The accepted answer uses a function `printf` that is present in Racket but not Scheme. Hence, the accepted answer does not actually work in Scheme. The answerer claims this is how stackoverflow normally works: If the question asks something but the tag is something else, the answer can be for the tag, e.g. the tag takes precedence. From the comments:

> @ÓscarLópez You are right it is tagged as racket, but both the title and the question body specifically ask how to do it in Scheme, not Racket. I guess this is an issue with the question itself. – xdavidliu yesterday    Delete
>
> @xdavidliu The tag takes precedence, that's how Stack Overflow normally works. Trust me on this one ;) – Óscar López yesterday

Is the second comment "The tag takes precedence, that's how Stack Overflow normally works." correct? Is there any documentation on Stackoverflow that supports that claim?

Comment: Sometimes, mistagged and/or unclear questions receive weird answers/unclear answers. :shrug: clearly the op found it to be useful enough to accept it.

Comment: You can suggest an edit to the question to replace Scheme with Racket. Worst thing that happens is that your edit is rejected.

Comment: "A *recent* question"? It's dated from 2016.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the technology, but if they said they're using Racket, and they accepted the answer that uses Racket, presumably that is in fact what they're using. Of course, if the code in the question is also valid in Scheme, then visitors to the site might see that question looking for a Scheme answer, so it might be useful to have both.

Comment: all reasonable comments. My question is specifically about the claim that "the tag takes precedence, that's how stackoverflow normally works". Is that part true?